# stratify python-weka-wrapper3 for train_test_split function

Tags: python-3.x, weka, train-test-split

Trying to do a train_test_split but the database is so unbalanced so i want to stratify it, how can i do it?

On the documentation I saw that train_test_split function just receive 2 arguments:

train_test_split(percentage, rnd=None)

so don't know if it's possible to do that with stratification.

My code is that:

```
train_model_1_ORG, test_model_1_ORG = data_modelos_1_2.train_test_split(70.0, Random(1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Weka doesn't offer that functionality.

However, I just committed a change to the `weka.core.Instances` class that allows you to generate cross-validation splits (method: `cv_splits`).

Since you want 70% in your training set, you could generate splits for a 10-fold CV and then combine 7 of the test splits into a training set and the others into a test set (using the `Instances.append_instances(Inst1, Inst2)` class method).

**NB:** You need to install pww3 [directly from Github](https://fracpete.github.io/python-weka-wrapper3/install.html#github) or use a release newer than 0.2.9.

Comment: When I try to execute this function I receive this error: 
AttributeError: 'Instances' object has no attribute 'cv_splits' but on the github of python-weka-wrapper3 I can see the function

Comment: Did you install pww3 straight from the repo (these changes haven't been made available as a release yet)? If yes, was there already a version of pww3 in your virtual environment present? If yes, uninstall that first before installing the new one (they both have the same version number).